# Yii2 preselect radiobutton value

Tags: yii2, active-form

I know I can use

```
 <?= $form  ->field($model, 'subject')
            ->textInput(array('value' => 'VALUE'))
            ->label('Titel'); ?>
```

to prefill a Textfield, but how can I do it for a radioList?

```
<?= $form  ->field($model, 'locations')
           ->radioList($regionen)
           ->label('Regionen');
```

I could use `->textInput` again but this transforms the whole List into a single Textfield

Alternativly: Is there a better way to modify a database record? Currently I'm trying to set all values into a new form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [radioButtonList checked by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735025/radiobuttonlist-checked-by-default)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the value that you want selected in the `locations` attribute of your `$model` and after rendering, it will be pre-selected in the radio list. That is:

```
$model->locations = ....
```

I assume that locations is a foreign key to some other table (or maybe a fixed list of strings).

Answer (score 2):

Referring the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#activeRadioList()-detail) :

Pass the second parameter, `options[]` to `radioList()`

```
$options = [
    'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {

        // check if the radio button is already selected
        $checked = ($checked) ? 'checked' : '';

        $return = '<label class="radio-inline">';
        $return .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" ' . $checked . '>';
        $return .= $label;
        $return .= '</label>';

        return $return;
    }
]

<?= $form->field($model, 'locations')
         ->radioList($regionen, $options)
         ->label('Regionen');
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: And how do i pass the correct value to the options ?